# Build libpng without PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED for linux

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, libpng

I need to build libpng, but without `#define PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED` in pnglibconf.h
I've read comments from `pnglibconf.dfa`, and here are some ways of disabling features, however I didn't manage to make what I want using them.
The problem is in that, build process is performed on build server, so I can't change any files inside of libpng submodule. Here is how server works:

1. Download clone sources from [git](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/releases/tag/v1.6.35beta01)
2. Generate makefile by running `cmake ..`
3. Run `make` command.

Thus I have libnpg, but with included `PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED` option.
Libpng is a submodule of my project, so it checked out by build server automatically so I can't change pnglibconf manually.
As it said in `pnglibconf.dfa` file:

> There are three ways of disabling features, in no particular order:
>
> 1) Create 'pngusr.h', enter the required private build information
>    detailed below and #define PNG_NO_<option> for each option you
>    don't want in that file in that file.  You can also turn on options
>    using PNG_<option>_SUPPORTED.  When you have finished rerun
>    configure and rebuild pnglibconf.h file with -DPNG_USER_CONFIG:
>
> make clean
>    CPPFLAGS='-DPNG_USER_CONFIG' ./configure
>    make pnglibconf.h
>
> pngusr.h is only used during the creation of pnglibconf.h, but it
>    is safer to ensure that -DPNG_USER_CONFIG is specified throughout
>    the build by changing the CPPFLAGS passed to the initial ./configure

I tried to do what is written here. I run `cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-DPNG_USER_CONFIG -I/home/me/dev/include"` where `/home/me/dev/include` - is a path to `pngusr.h` file

Then I run `make` command. However, PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED is still present in generated (by `make` command `pnglibconf.h` file).
So my main question is how to make libpng without `PNG_READ_eXIf_SUPPORTED` option?

Comment: What a convoluted build system!  I've studied it a bit, now, and I am unable to confirm that in-file comments you present reflect the true state of the current version of the library.  I am not certain that they don't, but you should consider that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It remains unclear to me whether and to what extent the specific customization mechanism you are trying to use works in the version of libpng you are trying to use.  But it looks like there's a simpler way.  Just below the excerpt you posted, in the same file, is the second (of three) alternatives:

> 2) Add definitions of the settings you want to change to `CPPFLAGS`;
>   for example:
>
> ```
> -DPNG_DEFAULT_READ_MACROS=0
> ```

(lightly formatted).  I'm not in a good position to test that on the CMake-based build system, but it seems to work like a charm in the Autotools build system.  From examining and comparing the two, I think it will work for CMake, too.  In particular, you would want to run

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CPP_FLAGS="-DPNG_NO_READ_eXIf"
```

for your particular case.

Note, by the way, that the CPP (i.e. preprocessor) flags are the right place for an option such as you are specifying (for `-DPNG_USR_CONFIG` in your original attempt, too). In practice, though, they probably still work in the C compiler flags.